# Date Struct is not properly being checked

Tags: c++, struct, while-loop, boolean

I have some C++ code:

```
#include <bjarne/std_lib_facilities.h>

struct Date {
    int month;
    int day;
    int year;
};

Date get_date();
Date get_birth_date();
int days_in_month (int month);
bool is_valid_date (const Date& date);
bool is_before (const Date& date1, const Date& date2);

int main()
{
    cout << "Welcome to Age Calculator!\n"; 
    Date current;
    current = get_date();
    cout << "Would you like to see how old you are (y/n)?";
    char answer, slash;
    cin >> answer;
    Date birthday;
    if(answer == 'y'){
        birthday = get_birth_date();
        bool valid = is_valid_date (birthday);
        bool before = is_before (current,birthday);
        while(!valid && !before){
            cout << "Invalid birth date?  Please re-enter: ";
            cin >> birthday.month >> slash >> birthday.day >> slash >> birthday.year;
            valid = is_valid_date (birthday);
            before = is_before (current,birthday);
        }
        cout << "Your birthday is: " << birthday.month << "/" << birthday.day << "/" << birthday.year << "\n";
    }
    else
    cout << "You are so chicken! \n";    
}

Date get_date()
{
    cout << "Please enter today's date (mm/dd/yyyy): ";
    Date today; 
    char slash;
    cin >> today.month >> slash >> today.day >> slash >> today.year;
    bool valid = is_valid_date (today);
    while(!valid){
        cout << "Invalid date?  Please re-enter: ";
        cin >> today.month >> slash >> today.day >> slash >> today.year;
        valid = is_valid_date (today);
    }
    cout << "Date entered was: " << today.month << "/" << today.day << "/" << today.year << "\n";
    return today;
}

Date get_birth_date()
{
    cout << "Please enter your birth date (mm/dd/yyyy): ";
    Date birth; 
    char slash;
    cin >> birth.month >> slash >> birth.day >> slash >> birth.year;
    return birth;
}

int days_in_month (int month)
{
    int month31[7] = {1,3,5,7,8,10,12};
    for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++){
        if(month == month31[i])
            return 31;
    }
    int month30[4] = {4,6,9,11};
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        if(month == month30[i])
            return 30;
    }
    if(month == 2)
        return 28;
}

bool is_valid_date (const Date& date)
{
    int months[12] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12};
    int days = 0; 
    for(int i = 0; i < 12; i++){
        if(date.month == months[i]){
            days = days_in_month (date.month);
            if(date.day <= days && date.day > 1){
                return true;
            }

    }
    return false;
}

bool is_before (const Date& date1, const Date& date2)
{
    cout << date1.day << " " << date2.day; 
    if(date2.year < date1.year){
        return true;
    }
    else if(date2.year == date1.year)
    {
        cout << "-";
        if(date2.month < date1.month)
            return true;
        else if(date2.month == date1.month){
            if(date2.day <= date1.day)
                return true;
        }
        else
            return false;

    }
    return false;
}
```

I know that the is_valid_date function works, but when I'm testing a birthday that comes **after** the current day entered, for some reason, it passes the is_before test and never goes to the while loop asking the user to enter a valid birthday. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Edit: The specific inputs that I'm testing are: for today's date, I enter 05/06/2015 and for a birthday, I enter 05/07/2015. It then prints the birthday, which means it skips the while loop in int main(), which it shouldn't do, since the birthday comes after the current date.

Comment: You might want to clean up some of your debug code before posting questions.  Some people might find it funny, but others may be offended :)

Comment: Yeah get rid of the swear word otherwise you're going to get down voted and/or your question closed :/

Comment: Ah, yeah, I'm really sorry I forgot to take it out! Thanks for the edit

Comment: It would also help if you posted the specific inputs that your code is failing on. For example, what are you entering for today's date and birth date which causes the unexpected behavior.

Comment: Your posted code for `is_valid_date` is missing a closing `}`. Is that an error in transcribing?

Comment: @RSahu Looks like Revision #2 removed the `}` by mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your condition is wrong:

```
while(!valid && !before)
```

Your condition tries to get a new birthday if the one entered is invalid **and** is after the current date. I think you want:

```
while(!valid || !before)
```

Which gets a new birthday if the one entered is invalid **or** is after the current date.

Answer (score 0):

You should change `while(!valid && !before)` to `while(!valid || !before)`.

You want to stay in the loop as long as the birth date is invalid **or** the birth date is after the current date. Currently, if you enter a valid date which is after the current date, it will break out of the loop because the first condition is false (the date is valid).